# recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: node.js, nginx, fs

I get error on nginx error log when trying to use nginx nodejs fs video stream. I had an error before about too many open files and fixed it by increasing worker connection. But now I get this error often:

> recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

and sometimes:

> upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

we use nginx on ubuntu 18.04 server with 2x CPU 2ghz 2 cores, 24ram

nginxConfig:

```
user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
worker_processes 2;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    log_format  main_ext  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$host" sn="$server_name" '
                      'rt=$request_time '
                      'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
                      'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
                      'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main_ext;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

nginx site config :

```
upstream http_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8087;
    keepalive 32;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name  cdn.amjilt.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 7070;
    listen [::]:7070;
    server_name  cdn.amjilt.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
   listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
   server_name  cdn.amjilt.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/media/media.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/media/media.key;

   ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   client_max_body_size 500M;
   client_body_buffer_size 500M;
   proxy_buffer_size   16M;
   proxy_buffers   24 8M;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_set_header Host $host;

   location /images{
        root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
   }
   location /tmp{
        root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
   }
   location /images/uploads{
        root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
   }
   location /images/avatar{
        root /home/ubuntu/projects/amjilt_media/static;
   }
   location /api/video/show{
        expires off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_pass http://http_backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
   }
   location /api/video/mobile{
        expires off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_pass http://http_backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
   }
   location /api/pdf/show{
        expires off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_pass http://http_backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
   }
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8087;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }

   gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
   gzip on;
}
```

Comment: is your problem resolved? Any solution for this?